# how to remove images from amazon mws catalog

Tags: amazon-mws

I have got 2 amazon account, US, UK (diff merchantId) and in UK account, i have got DE,ES,IT,FR account with the same merchantID as UK one.

the problem here is, last week in backend because of some issue images got duplicated and when i published the catalog, all images got duplicated in amazon accounts as well. I have spoken to catalog team and they said that they can not do anything unless i provide them the ASINS and only 7 ASINS per support case. I have got almost 9000 ASINS. I need to remove the duplicated images from my catalog and i dont know what to do..

I have published the image feed for 10 ASINS with Operation type 'DELETE' to delete all the images for that product and the response says successful BUT images are still there, I dont know why... i was reading somewhere that images are linked between accounts, so if i delete the images from my UK account, i still need to do the same for US account. i did the same with success response BUT still images are not being deleted from amazon...

can anyone tell me how to remove all images regardless of duplicated or not? and then i can update the images again with proper order.

appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

If you`d wish to delete single images you have two options:

1. Delete them manually in your inventory.
2. Create a file with the full list of ASINs and forward this list in a new case to Amazon Seller Support and ask them to delete the images on this ASINs. As this order will delete every image on this ASINs you`ll have to re-upload the residual images.

Info: Option 2 is just goodwill and I cannot confirm that every Seller Support associate will do that.

Thanks

Raz